# Downloading HTML File when modified

Tags: android, html, file, download, jsoup

I'm trying to implement a Class that is downloading a HTML-File and save this locally on my device. When the HTML-File changes I want to redownload the HTML-File and overwrite the existing one. After this I want to pass this HTML-File to Jsoup to work with it. However my Class is not working. The following Code gives me a "java.io.FileNotFoundException:/tabelle.html: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"
So rather my download isn't working at all or I have some missleading paths in my Code. Hope someone can help me ...

```
public class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressBar pBar;
    InputStream is;
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    ByteArrayBuffer baf;
    FileOutputStream fos;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... website) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(website[0]);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            long dateHttp = urlConnection.getLastModified();
            File file = new File("tabelle.html");
            long dateLocal = file.lastModified();
            if(dateLocal < dateHttp || file.exists() == false) {
                is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(1024);
                int current = 0;
                while((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
                }
                fos = openFileOutput("tabelle.html", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            try {
                is.close();
                bis.close();
                baf.clear();
                fos.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        try {
            File file = new File("tabelle.html");
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "CP1252", "");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewC4)).setText(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your exception handling is suboptimal. In case of "cache-hit" (not downloading HTML), `this.is` is null and it won't close your `fos`. You should have a try/catch for every `close()` operation or at least check whether the streams are `null`.

Comment: As well you could use `HttpURLConnection.setIfModifiedSince()` to unburden the webserver. If you get HTTP Code '304' (Not Modified) you have the same effect with less traffic and less battery drain.

Comment: Another thing. You shouldn't read the file in `onPostExecute`, because this happens on the Main-dispatching thread. Better move this to `doInBackground`. Enable `StrictMode` to get these "sins" visible.

Comment: Thanks hgoebl, I changed the exception handling and will read the file now on doInBackground and only set the Data to the UI on onPostExecute. It seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line `new File("tabelle.html");` it is creating a File in the Linux root partition, and that is a system exclusive area. Check on [THIS LINK][1] the proper way to access files in the disk on Android.

Remember that if you're going to use external storage (for your use-case I don't think you should) you need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

**edit:**

I noticed that you're writing to the file using `openFileOutput()`. That is a different location than when you create using `new File()`

as mentioned by @hgoebl, to get a file in the same location as `openFileOutput()` you should use `new File(getCacheDir(), "filename");` (or maybe `getDir()`) I honestly don't remember and you'll have to test it.

Comment: I'd probably use `getCacheDir()` for this purpose.